# Templates for nested attributes with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have an `Appointment` model, each instance of which has a `Client`. Here's my template for editing an appointment:

```
<form id="edit-appointment" name="appointment" class="mobile_friendly">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="start_time_ymd" id="start_time_ymd" value="<%= start_time_ymd %>" placeholder="Start Date">
    <input type="text" name="start_time_time" id="start_time_time" value="<%= start_time_time %>" placeholder="Start Time">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" value="<%= client.name %>" placeholder="Client">
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="<%= client.id %>" placeholder="Client ID">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="client_phone" id="client_phone" value="<%= client.phone %>" placeholder="Phone">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" value="<%= notes %>" placeholder="Notes">
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Update Appointment" />
  </div>

</form>

<a href="#/index/<%= stylist_id %>">Back</a>
```

My problem is that my `Client` attributes aren't being passed to the server correctly. The JSON object that gets passed to the server on save looks something like the following. Let's pretend I have a client with phone number `555-555-5555` but I change it to `555-555-1234` and then submit the form:

```
{"appointment":
  {"start_time_ymd":"1/1/2000",
   "client_phone":"555-555-1234",
   "client":{"phone":"555-555-5555"}}
```

I've omitted a lot of irrelevant fields, but hopefully you see what I mean. I've changed `client_phone` from `555-555-5555` to `555-555-1234`, but the `client` object in the JSON object has its phone number unchanged. I need to somehow change that phone number.

How do I make these fields - like the phone number field - actually "take" so they get passed to the server as part of the `client` object under `appointment` and not directly under `appointment`? I'm using Backbone-relational, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work like this:

```
class Snip.Views.Appointments.EditView extends Backbone.View
  template : JST["backbone/templates/appointments/edit"]

  events :
    "submit #edit-appointment" : "update"

  update : (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    # THE ONLY CHANGE I MADE WAS TO ADD THIS LINE
    @model.attributes.client.phone = $("#client_phone").val()

    @model.save(null,
      success : (appointment) =>
        @model = appointment
        window.location.hash = "/#index/" + @model.attributes.stylist_id
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

if after you change the form text your model is not being updated then you need to update the data explicitly

```
SampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#formEl',
events : {
    "change input" :"changed",
    "change select" :"changed"
},

initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, "changed");
},
changed:function(evt) {
   var changed = evt.currentTarget;
   var value = $("#"+changed.id).val();
   var obj = "{\""+changed.id +"\":\""+value+"\"";

   // Add Logic to change the client phone
   if (changed.id === 'client_phone') {
          obj = obj + "client\":{\"phone\":\""+value+"\""};
   }
   obj = obj + "}";
   var objInst = JSON.parse(obj);
   this.model.set(objInst);            
}
});
```

Reference : 
[Can I bind form inputs to models in Backbone.js without manually tracking blur events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074636/can-i-bind-form-inputs-to-models-in-backbone-js-without-manually-tracking-blur-e)

You can also bind to model change event

```
    model.on('change:client_phone', 
       function () { 
           //Set client value here  
       });
```