# What exactly happens when you save a Backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What exactly happens when you  save a Backbone model? Here's the best I can piece together by reading the documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

1. `model.save([attributes], [options])` is called
2. A "change" event is fired (but only if the attributes are new)
3. The server is notified of the change?
4. A "sync" event is called once the server returns

But I'm a Backbone noob and I'm sure someone else could do a way better job of explaining.

I'm partly just curious what happens. I'm also having trouble understanding how Backbone comes up with the JSON object it sends to the server. I'm having a [separate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414271/templates-for-nested-attributes-with-backbone) where the JSON object is not what I want it to be, but I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The detailed process can be found in the [annotated source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) for [Backbone.Model.save](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-56) and [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-134).

If you ignore `options.wait` and `options.silent`, your decomposition is mostly correct.

When you issue a `model.save`:

1. the attributes passed to the function are set, a change event is fired if the values changed
2. `save` delegates the request to `model.sync` or `Backbone.sync`
3. `sync` serializes the data to a JSON string by calling `JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())`
4. An Ajax request is sent to sent to server, a POST request for a new object, a PUT for an update. The target URL is defined by `model.url` (or `collection.url/id`)
5. When the request completes, the model is updated with the server response, if any, and triggers a `change` event accordingly.
6. Success or error callbacks are called, a `sync` event is triggered if no success callback is defined.

Usually, you can customize this behaviour by overriding `model.toJSON` or `model.sync`

Comment: Step six changed in Backbone 0.9.9. See http://backbonejs.org/#changelog     Consolidated "sync" and "error" events within Backbone.sync. They are now triggered regardless of the existence of success or error callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

first,I suggest you read the source code of the backbone, is really very simple.Default backbone and server-side interaction is achieved through backbone.sync.

second,You can trace debug model.save method of code again, naturally know the details.
I suggest you start here：
http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html